# losing object when calling [[.. alloc] init]

Tags: objective-c

I'm experiencing a strange problem when calling alloc/init:

When I call:

```
Card *card = [[Card alloc] init];
return card; //here debugger reports that card is an NSMutableArray*, not a Card*
```

However, if I call:

```
Card *card = [Card alloc];
[card init];
return card; //here debugger reports that card is Card*
```

Card is declared as

```
@interface Card : NSObject { ...
```

I've experienced this exact same pattern with other object allocations in my code.  Its as though the object is getting released before the return, or the stack is getting stepped on.

I understand that I'm supposed to use alloc/init together, but am having this problem.

Comment: If those two examples yield different results, it points to a bugin your `init` method. Please post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your `init` function return `self`?  My guess would be that it isn't, and that's probably your problem.